# Extending Linear Functional over Polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

As I've been reading over some papers on linear functionals, I've noted a large distinction is made between linear operators $T: \mathbb{C}_n[z] \to \mathbb{C}[z]$ and linear operators $T: \mathbb{C}[z] \to \mathbb{C}[z]$, where $\mathbb{C}_n[z] \subset \mathbb{C}[z]$ is the set of complex polynomials of degree of most $n$.

As I've thought about this, it seems to me that if $T: \mathbb{C}[z] \to  \mathbb{C}[z]$ then surely we can view $T$ as a mapping from $\mathbb{C}_n[z]$ to $\mathbb{C}[z]$ by considering $T|_{\mathbb{C}_n[z]}$, i.e. the restriction of $T$ to $\mathbb{C}[z]$. However, I can't think of any concrete examples that show the converse is false, i.e. that a linear functional on $\mathbb{C}_n[z]$ cannot be extended to a linear functional on $\mathbb{C}[z]$.

The only examples I can think of *do* have an extension; for example, if we let $T(p(z)) = \sqrt{p^{(n+1)}(z)}$ then surely $T$ is linear on $\mathbb{C}_n[z]$ and is not linear on $\mathbb{C}[z]$, but $T$ can be extended to $\mathbb{C}[z]$ by defining $T(p(z)) = 1$. My question is thus as follows:

*Does there exist a linear functional mapping $\mathbb{C}_n[z]$ to $\mathbb{C}[z]$ that does not extend to a linear functional mapping $\mathbb{C}[z]$ to $\mathbb{C}[z]$?*

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not such a linear functional. Because if $\alpha\colon\mathbb{C}_n[z]\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}[z]$ is a linear functional, you can define $A\colon\mathbb{C}[z]\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}[z]$ by$$A(a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_mz^m)=\begin{cases}\alpha(a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_mz^m)&\text{ if }m\geqslant n\\\alpha(a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $A$ is linear and $A|_{\mathbb{C}_n[z]}=\alpha$.

More generally, if $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $U$ is a vector subspace of $V$, then every linear map $f\colon U\longrightarrow W$ can be extended to a linear map $F\colon V\longrightarrow W$.

Comment: Forgive my confusion, but if $\alpha(p(z)) = \exp\left(p^{(n)}(z)\right)$, then how are you proposing extending $\alpha$?

Comment: Since $\alpha(0)=1\neq0$, $\alpha$ is not linear.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Forgive my naiveness in this - I haven't need to touch linear algebra in a long time - it just so happens a bit of complex analysis I'm studying now relies on it. So if we were to, say, consider $\alpha(p(z)) = \sqrt{p^{(n+1)}(z)}$ (which should just be the zero map when restricted to $n$th degree polynomials if I'm not mistaken), then how do I extend it? I seem to be missing something here, because if $m > n$ I would naively think that $\alpha(a_0 + \cdots a_m z^m)$ would return $\sqrt{\frac{d^{n+1}}{dz^{n+1}}(a_0 + \cdots a_m z^m)}$ which doesnt seem linear

Comment: Since $\alpha\bigl(p(z)\bigr)=0$, you can extend it to the null function from $\mathbb{C}[z]$ into itself.

Comment: Ok, I *think* that makes sense. So when defining $A$ as we do in your post, I shouldn't be thinking about the extension using the same definition of $\alpha$ as I started with? e.g. even though $\alpha(p(z)) = \sqrt{p^{(n+1)}(z)} = 0$ on $\mathbb{C}_n[z]$, in extending $\alpha$ I need to choose the appropriate definition $\alpha = 0$? That seems to be like an equivalence relation over the mappings equal on $\mathbb{C}_n[z]$, but then how do we know which definition of $\alpha$ will work?

Comment: If we extend your $\alpha$ the way I did in my post, we will also get $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Hmm. I still can't say I understand, but I will think on this. In reading other posts on this subject, I have seen some people define $\alpha(a_0 + \cdots a_n z^n + a_{n+1} z^{n+1} \cdots a_m z^m) = \alpha(a_0 + \cdots a_n z^n)$, which makes sense to me, but I must admit I don't get how to use the definition your propose when $m \ge n$. You say that when I define $\alpha(p(z)) = \sqrt{p^{(n+1)}(z)}$ we get $\alpha = 0$, which makes sense to me if we define $\alpha(a_0 + \cdots a_n z^n + a_{n+1} z^{n+1} \cdots a_m z^m) = \alpha(a_0 + \cdots a_n z^n)$....

Comment: But doesn't make sense to me if we define $\alpha(a_0 + \cdots a_n z^n + a_{n+1} z^{n+1} \cdots a_m z^m) = \alpha(a_0 + \cdots a_n z^n + a_{n+1} z^{n+1} \cdots a_m z^m)$ as your post states, because we dont have $0 = \sqrt{\frac{d^{n+1}}{dz^{n+1}}(a_0 + \cdots a_m z^m)}$. Nevertheless, perhaps I am missing something here, so I will think on it.

Comment: As a last note, you mention this extends to all vector spaces at the bottom of your post, though every proof I can find is only for finite dimensional spaces. Just to make sure, does it hold true for all infinite dimensional spaces as well?

Comment: Yes, it does, but it is easier to prove for finite-dimensional vector spaces.